# Files are not getting updated in the docker container upon changes from the host

Tags: docker

I have a react app that I am mapping from host to Docker container by doing `docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v /$(pwd):/app 09b10e9fda85` but the changes done in *app.js* in the react app(host files) are not displaying up when I refresh the page at port 3000. I referred to this issue [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793) but it doesn't lead me to any conclusion. I even tried to achieve the same by making a *docker-compose.yml* file and then running it using `docker-compose up` but no mapping seems to take place in the real-time here as well.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services: 
  web: 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes: 
    - /app/node_modules
    - .:/app
```

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Where am I going wrong here?
I am using Docker for desktop version 17.03.1-ce-rc1, build 3476dbf, Windows 10 pro and the latest version of VS Code. Is this happening because of the Windows environment? as the video I followed did the same on a Macbook and everything there was working fine.

Comment: The explanation (about inodes change) from the thread you linked to seems to be reasonable, but in my understanding, this should only affect single-file mounts, while your mounts seem to be directories. Is that true? If yes, probably, the linked thread is not about your case.

Comment: Yes, the link that I have provided was the only viable issue that I found.

Comment: Try to add a trailing slash to the node_modules volume: `/app/node_modules/`

Comment: @Oresztesz Still getting the same results.

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile to the question?

Comment: @Oresztesz Added in the revision

Comment: Are you using Docker Toolbox on Windows with Virtualbox? This can be an issue with the Virutalbox shared folders.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Can you give an example of a change your host is making? Like for example, are you doing something like this on the host: `touch $(pwd)/random_file` and `random_file` doesn't appear in the container's `/app` directory?

Comment: @Perplexabot see the latest revision.

Comment: @Oresztesz No, I am using Docker for desktop in Windows 10 pro

Comment: May be related to the fact that file system change notifications are not working on windows. Did you try to restart the server in the container after making the change? See also https://forums.docker.com/t/file-system-watch-does-not-work-with-mounted-volumes/12038

Comment: @Henry I tried restarting the container but the system change notifications do not seem to work thereafter. Acc. to the forum you shared, the problem seems to persist in the Windows environment and after going through the conversations there it seems like the docker team hasn't figured out a solution yet. Can you try doing the same on a Windows machine and give a confirmation so that I would be sure that the problem is prevalent to Windows only.

Comment: Change notifications are not working on Windows (that's a known fact). However, the container sees the changed files. So starting the container with a shell as main process and then do `npm run start` whenever you changed something should work.